# Azure Web App naked URL redirects but www does not

Tags: azure, dns

I have a web app deployed on Azure and I'm trying to make it so both `<myurl>.com` and `www.<myurl>.com` work. Right now I have both domains listed on Azure within my webapp. `www.<myurl>.com` is registered as a CNAME from www to `<myurl>.azurewebsites.net` in godaddy. I have an A record from @ to the IP address shown by Azure, as well as a TXT record from @ to the given DNS by Azure `<myurl>.azurewebsites.net`

The problem is when I go to `http://<myurl>.com` it will change the URL to `<myurl>.azurewebsites.net` but when I go to `http://www.<myurl>.com` the URL is does not change.

Below are my go daddy DNS records. Most of these were there when I bought the domain so I'm not sure what they do. There is an A record that I can't seem to edit and I don't know what that IP address belongs to either.

[image]

Comment: Do you use a rewrite rule in your web app configuration file?

Comment: @NancyXiong I don't remember adding any rewrite but it has been a while since I touched this web app service. How can I check?

Comment: Do you have [added both hostnames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#enable-the-cname-record-mapping-in-azure) like `example.com` and `www.example.com` in the custom domains of App Service main page on the Azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

Alot of this can be done with an A and a CNAME. You will need to add both "www" and "awverify.www" in your DNS, and do those corresponding entries in the Azure portal.

Here's good doc:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/07/05/azure-app-service-how-to-configure-a-custom-domain/

Here's alot more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

The Azure portal will also give clues on what to do.